# Trying to make an array of meshes follow a path without distortion

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I am currently trying to make a curved railing, i am doing this by making an array of poles but im trying to figure how to curve them using a curve (sorta like the curve modifier) but without any distortion on the original mesh (the poles), any way i can do this in Blender 3.4?